# Como colocar um exe deentro do form vb.net

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Bom, eu tenho o código

```
Dim proc As Process
proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
proc.WaitForInputIdle()
' Set the panel control as the application's parent
SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.BetaBox.Handle)
'Maximize application
SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0)
```

Ele executa direito, porém eu queria que ele coloca-se o processo dentro do form mesmo abrindo diretamente, tem algum jeito? Precisa de while algo parecido?

Comment: Resumindo, você quer colocar a janela principal (*Form*) do processo dentro de sua própria *Form*? Se for isso, a resposta é **não é possível**. Ao menos que você tente emular o executável dentro de um container implementado com virtualização, mas para isso iria demorar muito trabalho. É bem complicado.

Comment: e possivel eu ja vi um programa utilizando o mesmo, ao abrir o programa clicando no atalha, ou diratamente no exe o programa reconhece o Process ID e envia para para o form, assim emulando dentro da form, sem ocupar espaço na barra de atalhos do explorer

Comment: Sim, ai é um contêiner de aplicativos, você teria que implementar um.

Comment: sim, eu gostaria de saber como é :P não tenho a base de como fazer apenas esse code acima funciona eu utilizo dessa forma, irei atualizar

Answer (score 0):

```
   <DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
    Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
    Const HTCAPTION As Long = 2
    Private Declare Function ReleaseCapture Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Long
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        If m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN Then
            ReleaseCapture()
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, &H0)
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub Soul_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Soul.Click

                Dim proc As Process
                proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
                proc.WaitForInputIdle()
                ' Set the panel control as the application's parent
                SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.CommandLog.Handle)
                ' Maximize application
                SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0)
        End Sub
```

esse codigo funciona ao clicar no botão, mas eu queria que ele reconhecesse o aplicativo assim que o aplicativo abrisse, sem precisar de botão etc.